# JavaScript : Mutation Occurring When Looping and Adding to a Database(mongoDB)

Tags: javascript, mongodb

**What I'm doing:**

Simply I'm creating a club. Adding users to club. Repeat.

**What's happening:**

I'm experiencing what appears to be a possible mutation or scope issue when looping
through a list and adding objects to a database.

I was able to fix it by creating a new object with an object literal constructor before
storing in the database, but that part of me that really wants to understand JavaScript
has to know what happend here.

**Problem:**

The issue is that inside of the inner function `addUser` the argument `user`
appears to eventually be mutated with an (_id) property unless I make a copy `newUser`.
This mutation causes the database to reject the insert because it sees a duplicate identifer.

**Error:**

**$*id* dup key: { : ObjectId('56adfbfec9f7477c5da5c2cb') }]
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'E11000 duplicate key error index:...**

The Main Loop:

```
UserUtils.prototype.createUsers = function (users,club) {

    return ClubFactory.createNewClub(club).then(function(clubID){

    users.forEach(function(user){ 
        ClubController.addUser(user,clubID);
    });

}
```

The inner function:

```
ClubUtils.prototype.addUser = function(user,clubID) {

    MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {

        if (err) {
            console.log('Unable to connect to the mongoDB server. Error:', err);
        } else {

            var newUser = {   //This will stop the mutation
                name: user.name,
                clubID: clubID
            }

            user["clubID"] = clubID;

            var clubsCollection = db.collection('clubs');
            //clubsCollection.insertOne(user, function (err, result) {
            clubsCollection.insertOne(newUser, function (err, result) {

                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    console.log("newUser");
                    console.log(newUser);
                    console.log("user");//this will be mutated with _id
                    console.log(user);
                } 
                db.close();
            });
        }
    });

}
```

The Docs for `insertOne` can be found [here](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/api/Collection.html#insertOne)

**Question:**

Is this really a mutation issue? If so, am I handling it correctly?

Comment: Where are you getting users from?  As in, what's the model of your data source?

Comment: It is schema-less data(i.e. no model), and the users object was parsed just before from a JSON file.

Comment: Looks like this might be the behavior of the driver with the `forceServerObjectId` option.  Pass `{ forceServerObjectId: true}` as the second argument to your `insertOne()` and see if the mutation still occurs.

Comment: @metame : interesting  I always interpreted that option as the "app server" would be responsible for the _id creation beforehand and therefore it wouldn't be created by the database. I can see now how it could be the "db server" it is really referring to. I'll let you know.